# What is the difference between utf8mb4_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_nopad_ci?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, utf8mb4

I chose the utf8mb4 character set for my database.

What is the difference between the utf8mb4_unicode_ci and the utf8mb4_unicode_nopad_ci collations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/supported-character-sets-and-collations/)

> A 'nopad' as part of the name indicates that the collation is of type NO PAD as opposed to PADSPACE ... NO PAD collations regard trailing spaces as normal characters.

On [PADSPACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/char/#description)

> CHAR (as well as VARCHAR and TEXT) values are compared without regard for trailing spaces. This does not apply to the LIKE pattern-matching operator, which takes into account trailing spaces.

> If a unique index consists of a column where trailing pad characters are stripped or ignored, inserts into that column where values differ only by the number of trailing pad characters will result in a duplicate-key error.